# focus:outline-none not working Tailwind CSS with Laravel

Tags: css, laravel, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind CSS for my Laravel application, and want to remove the focus border on the input boxes. According to the documentation, `focus:outline-none` should achieve this, although it is not working for me and the border still appears on focus.

It looks like I am targeting the wrong thing, as if I do `focus:outline-black`, I can see a black outline as well as the standard blue one on focus.

`focus:border-none` also does not fix the problem.

Any ideas?

```html
<input class="text-input" placeholder="Your Name" />

.text-input {
    @apply focus:outline:none;
}
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'jit',
    purge: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './vendor/laravel/jetstream/**/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Nunito', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },            
        },
        colors: {                      
            black: colors.black,
            white: colors.white,
            gray: colors.trueGray,
            indigo: colors.indigo,
            red: colors.rose,
            yellow: colors.amber,
            blue: colors.blue,
        },
    },

    plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms'), require('@tailwindcss/typography')],
};
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ]);

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

Comment: Did you compile your assets after adding the outline? Maybe the purge is enabled and is causing the problem.

Comment: Yes I did, got `npm run watch` constantly running

Comment: Well I think it's something else.. Can you update your question with the contents of your `tailwind.config.js` and your `webpack.mix.js` (if you use webpack)?

Comment: @Dennis sorry for slow response, I have updated the question with those now

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Having same issue right now, Laravel 8, Inertia, Breeze & Tailwind: when I set `outline-none` on a element, it is ignored. Everything else seems to work properly.

The only thing which solved it was to add css: `border-transparent focus:border-transparent focus:ring-0` on the element itself.

Comment: Thank you - I have a border on the bottom edge of my input, so didn't use the `border-transparent`, but the `focus:ring-0` seemed to work fine on its own anyway. However, it was changing the color of my bottom border, but I just fixed this by setting the focus border color to the same as the non-focus color... if that makes sense!

Comment: The problem is the cheboxes' default focus:ring, as shown above. It's never set to 0, by default on checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks @kamil_b, If anyone didn't want to make the border to be transparent you can use `focus:border-[your_color_code] focus:ring-0`. It works for me

Comment: Worked like magic. Thanks.

Comment: At the end of the day ```border-0 focus:ring-0``` was enough, never thank you enough for the ```ring-0``` <3

Answer (score 51):

```css
!outline-none
```

This fixed it for me.

Comment: what does `!` mean ?

Comment: It's an important modifier, [tailwind docs here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important-modifier).

Comment: It works! None of other does!

Answer (score 28):

Maybe you can try add `focus:outline-none` direct in your class.

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/p73xfy1h/

Comment: No luck unfortunatley

Comment: This works perfect.

Comment: this did it for me.

Comment: This work for me using vite/vue3

Answer (score 26):

The proper way: `border-none focus:ring-0` You don't need to bother making a border transparent if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Both solutions worked - this one seems to be cleaner and more logical :)

Comment: I was trying to remove blue outline when an input is focused, this one worked but has a small bug. I have a `focus:border-b` class on my input, adding `focus:ring-0` helped disable the blue border but, now the bottom border I added turned blue

Answer (score 16):

just use focus:ring-0 focus:ring-offset-0 both.

```
focus:ring-0 focus:ring-offset-0
```

Comment: This works Today

Answer (score 10):

the correct way to handle this is in Tailwind 3 `focus:ring-transparent`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

There is a simple way to solve this problem: use outline

```
outline:none
```

Comment: `outline-none` is the correct answer in tailwindcss

Answer (score 4):

working with this:

```
focus:border-current focus:ring-0
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using MudBlazor together with TailwindCSS and found that my input text/select boxes all had an odd square border when focused.

[image: Before]

I located the Tailwind CSS responsible and declared the CSS again at the end of the page `<head>` and also included `!important` on the overwritten attributes to ensure I have disabled it.

```
[type='text']:focus, [type='email']:focus, [type='url']:focus, [type='password']:focus, [type='number']:focus, [type='date']:focus, [type='datetime-local']:focus, [type='month']:focus, [type='search']:focus, [type='tel']:focus, [type='time']:focus, [type='week']:focus, [multiple]:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus {
    outline: 0px !important;
    outline-offset: 0px !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

[image: After]

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem, when I clicked on the `<input />` tag it flashed a white border, this solved my problem:

```
outline outline-transparent
```

I'm on tailwindcss@3.2.4, next@13.4.9 and react@18.2.0.

Answer (score 2):

focus:ring-0, this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

this is my configuration when working with TailwindCSS `<input />`

```
border                 // border-width: 1px;
border-slate-700       // DEFAULT border-color
hover:border-slate-500 // HOVER border-color
focus:border-blue-500  // WHEN WRITE border-color
focus:outline-none     // NONE OUTLINE WHEN WRITE
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me - `focus:!ring-offset-0`

I am using next js with shadcn ui. the `!` is a important modifier.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `Laravel`, `Tailwind`, and `Material UI`. This snippet solved the problem. It wasn't the `ring`, `outline`, or `border`; it was the `box-shadow` from `TailwindCSS`.

To solve the conflict, add the snippet below to the `app.css`:

```css
input:focus, input:hover{ 
    box-shadow:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had set it in the global SCSS file, and in my case, the outline was fixed.

```
[type='text'] {
  --tw-ring-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
control: (base, state) => ({
 ...base,
 "*": {
        boxShadow: "none !important",
       },
}),
```

Or you can visit the issue in the repo: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2728

In my case I resolved in **ReactJS**, the problem started when I added the plugin **tailwindcss/fomrs** for edit checkbox color and I realized that many components changed because this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ***focus:ring-0***. I hope it's solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me.

```
focus-visible:ring-0
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. **It would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

at least in 2024 the real reason is "forms" included in the tailwind config, if you remove it from the plugins section, outlines are back to normal and elements are not bloated in size ignoring e.g. box sizing and other odd things.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me with tailwind `^3.2.4`

```html
<input
  type="text"
  class="focus-visible:outline-none"
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

just add class="focus:!outline-none" . it worked just fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-blue-500

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).